# cant "addAction" to IntentFilter in android

Tags: android, intentfilter

Hi.  I am an Android beginner trying to make an IntentFilter that can filter multiple  actions.  Unfortunately, when I begin using the `addAction` method, Eclipse  throws an error:

> "Syntax error on token "addAction",
>   Identifier expected after this token"

even though I have imported the required file.  This is probably a settings issue even though I am unsure why rest of the code doesnt show any problems.

Here is my code stub:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

...

private Context mContext;
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
```

I observed one more thing--as I type ' filter.' nothing shows up, just the message "No Default Proposals"

Can anybody  help me?

Comment: You probably need to show more sorrounding code, not just a small excerpt. May be your `filter` variable are out of the scope or something else...

Comment: out of scope ?? did not  understand ??  i havent  declared the IntentFilter in inside any methods  , following  that                      mContext.registerReceiver(status_Handler,TMS);                                                                                           here too while trying to  registerReceiver , I get errors  saying "Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
 - Syntax error on token "(", delete this token"            "status_Handler"  is my broadcast  reciever method... has anyone  ever  faced  the..the error  statment i got

Comment: If you post your code, i can try to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading your comment above in the question ("*Multiple markers at this line - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token*, etc.), I still think it is a bracket (or parenthesis) mismatch problem that does not let Eclipse understand the code. It could be in another method. Check carefully all your file. You may try to remove most of your code (just copy it to notepad) until you narrow the issue.

---

From the [**dev guide**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) (emphasis mine):

> An intent filter is an instance of the IntentFilter class. However, since the Android system must know about the capabilities of a component before it can launch that component, **intent filters are generally not set up in Java code, but in the application's manifest file** (AndroidManifest.xml) as  elements. (The **one exception** would be filters for broadcast receivers that are registered dynamically by calling Context.registerReceiver(); they are directly created as IntentFilter objects.)

I would add this to your manifest instead:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/screen_off">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: well  yes i but  precisely im  tryig to  create a  intent  filter just  to  register a  broadcast  listner.

Comment: What it does not make any sense is the "syntax error" message. Make sure you do not have any missing (or extra) bracket somewhere.

Comment: no  brackets  issue  infact i have followed  one of the  test  stubs  given  here  and  android  developer  site... this is  what is really  bugging such   stupid  error  which  i cant make  any sense... any idea  why i cant  see any  "No Default Proposals" for the  "filter"  Intent  filter  i  made ..i have hunch that is  the  problem..

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to run code outside of a method scope, which is illegal in Java (unless it's an assignment). If you change the code to

```
private Context mContext;
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
{
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
}
```

it will run as part of the object constructor.

Comment: I think this best answers the question. The marked answer is sort of tackling a different concept.