# How to use IntentFilter programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

When i try Intent filter on Manifest file, it worked well
But, when i try it on Java which make me to create an IntentFilter object, it didn't work

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Intent dialIntent;
IntentFilter filter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnDial = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDial);
    final EditText txtNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
    btnDial.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:"+(txtNumber.getText().toString())));
            Uri data = dialIntent.getData();

            filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(dialIntent.getAction());
            filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            filter.addDataScheme(data.getScheme());

            startActivity(dialIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Is it only valid on BroadcastReceiver?
I already try it but nothing happens.
How can i register an IntentFilter programmatically?
I'm still a beginner on Android Programming.
Please give me some explanation about this

Comment: You created the filter, but you didn't do anything with it. You need to register a listener for the filter. What do you want to happen when there is an Intent that matches the filter? Show the part you had put in your manifest and we can show you how to do this same thing in code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to dial any number and To dial a particular number you can use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + YOUR_NUMBER));
startActivity(intent);
```

There is no need to use intent filter.

Though you can check out this link...may be it will help you.

[cant “addAction” to IntentFilter in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098901/cant-addaction-to-intentfilter-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am using Intent.ACTION_CALL is just an example.
I already try it with intent filter via manifest and it worked well, there is a pop up about how you run the code after a click event.
But i don't know how to register IntentFilter programmatically (in Java, not Manifest)
That's exactly what i asked

Comment: you can use your action in place of ACTION_CALL also.